# Post picture to facebook group without prompting for permissions?

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to use flash banner to browse for a picture file, then pass it to php script which uploads it to a facebook group album without prompting for permissions?

Comment: even if im the admin of the group and i set offline access oauth token in the php receiving the file?

Comment: you will still have to request permission for offline access.

Answer (score 0):

You'd best read the Facebook Api documentation, and especially the [part on authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: I did - should i authenticate myself and get offline access token to upload picture without prompting?